# Opentsdb Port is Websocket Port or Http Port?

Tags: opentsdb

I am  beginner to opentsdb and the opentsdb port 4242 is a websocket port or any other port ? How the data is transferred to server ?

Answer (score 1):

Port 4242 is used for two different protocols: HTTP and a telnet-like line-delimited plain-ASCII "protocol".  Data is typically retrieved via HTTP (using the [OpenTSDB API](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/index.html)) and is typically pushed using either [the HTTP API](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html) or the [telnet-like protocol](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing.html#telnet).

Comment: I am Beginner to this project and We hope you guys are expert ? Is there any changes to your answer :)